# DD4T Web application upgraded with Tridion 9 CIL unable to pull images

Tags: dd4t, sites-9, content-service

I am running into an images issue, where DD4T application is able to pull page content but not images. Following exception is thrown on image request.

> [DataServiceClientException: BadRequest]
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery() +478
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute(DataServiceContext
>   context, QueryComponents queryComponents) +254
>   [DataServiceQueryException: An error occurred while processing this
>   request.]
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute(DataServiceContext
>   context, QueryComponents queryComponents) +628
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.InnerSynchExecute(Uri
>   requestUri, String httpMethod, Nullable`1 singleResult,
>   OperationParameter[] operationParameters) +519
>
>   Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceContext.Execute(Uri requestUri) +136
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.<>c__DisplayClass23_1`1.b__1() +87
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Caching.CacheHandlers.DefaultMemCache.DefaultMemCacheHandler`1.SetOrGetExisting(String
>   key, String region, Func`1 valueFactory, CacheItemPolicy
>   cacheItemPolicy) +83
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.<>c__DisplayClass23_0`1.b__0() +479
>   [ServiceQueryException: Failed to execute query]
>   DD4T.Factories.BinaryFactory.TryFindBinary(String url, String
>   localPath, Boolean retrieveData, IBinary& binary) in
>   C:\projects\dd4t-core\source\DD4T.Factories\BinaryFactory.cs:269
>   DD4T.Factories.BinaryFactory.FindAndStoreBinary(String url, String
>   physicalPath) in
>   C:\projects\dd4t-core\source\DD4T.Factories\BinaryFactory.cs:40
>   DD4T.Web.Binaries.BinaryFileManager.ProcessRequest(HttpRequest
>   request) +251
>   DD4T.Web.Binaries.BinaryDistributionModule.DistributionModule_OnPreRequestHandlerExecute(Object
>   o, EventArgs eventArgs) +289
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +223   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +213   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +91

Following exception is logged when DD4T logging is enabled

> DEBUG 2019-09-18 07:35:13,662 66590ms DefaultLogger          Debug
>   - started GetBinaryMetaByUrl for url /ush/en/us/files/images/CNP_640x400_V2.jpg with publication id 91
>   DEBUG 2019-09-18 07:35:13,662 66590ms DefaultLogger          Debug
>   - using encodedUrl: /ush/en/us/files/images/CNP_640x400_V2.jpg WARN  2019-09-18 07:35:13,670 66598ms DefaultLogger          TryFindBinary
>   - Caught unexpected exception while retrieving binary with url /ush/en/us/files/images/CNP_640x400_V2.jpg (requested url:
>   /ush/en/us/files/images/CNP_640x400_V2.jpg. Error message: Failed to
>   execute query    at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService.HandleHttpResponseCode(Exception
>   e, Int32 statusCode)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.AbstractODataService.HandleException(Exception
>   e)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.ODataV4Service.<>c__DisplayClass23_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
>   at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.PerformRetry[T](Func`1 block, Int32
>   retryCount)    at Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.Utils.Retry[T](Func`1
>   block, Int32 retryCount, Boolean locking)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.Meta.AbstractMetaFactory.DoExecuteFunc[T](ODataV4ClientFunction
>   func, Boolean expectSingleItem)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Caching.CacheHandlers.DefaultMemCache.DefaultMemCacheHandler`1.SetOrGetExisting(String
>   key, String region, Func`1 valueFactory, CacheItemPolicy
>   cacheItemPolicy)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.Meta.AbstractMetaFactory.ExecuteFunc[T](ODataV4ClientFunction
>   func, Boolean expectSingleItem)    at
>   Sdl.Web.Delivery.Dynamic.Meta.BinaryMetaFactory.GetMetaByURL(Int32
>   publicationId, String urlPath)    at
>   DD4T.Providers.Tridion9.CIL.TridionBinaryProvider.GetBinaryMetaByUrl(String
>   url) in
>   C:\projects\dd4t-providers-tridion9-cil\source\DD4T.Providers.Tridion9.CIL\TridionBinaryProvider.cs:line
>   214    at DD4T.Factories.BinaryFactory.TryFindBinary(String url,
>   String localPath, Boolean retrieveData, IBinary& binary) in
>   C:\projects\dd4t-core\source\DD4T.Factories\BinaryFactory.cs:line 198

We had deployed the same DD4t application in lower environments where we were able to access images and content, but it's only in staging environment we are running into an issue.

Any pointers to resolve the issue is highly appreciated!

Comment: 1. Any error on session-content service?  
2. Is that session-content service running? 
3. validate with postman request directly with CIL ODataV4?   
4. Is that odatav4 endpoint working?

Comment: Yes, session content service is up and running.   I am able to see the binary information returned for http://abc:8081//client/v2/content.svc/Binaries.  in the browser yet to verify in postman.

Comment: After troubleshooting we found its issue with load balancer.  We pointed DD4T web app to point to the fully qualified servername content service url instead of the load balancer one.  We are still working through the soultion, shall post it here once its inplace.  Thanks for the suggestions and inputs posted.

Comment: I was going to say it would be good to use the latest hotfix (api role / .net) instead of relying on the Sdl.Web.Delivery 11.0 Nuget package. For one of my own projects I created a Nuget package of my own with the latest hotfix and pushed that to a private Nuget repository. But I just noticed that SDL have released a new version for 11.0 (which probably serves as a hotfix rollup), namely 11.0.1055. You could try upgrading to that, regardless of the outcome of your load balancer change.

Comment: Thanks Quirjin, shall reach out SDL and get the hotfix.

Comment: We fixed issue by rewriting response header at the ngnix level and giving full control on  iis users to the proxy service.   Thanks for sharing your inputs.  Appreciate your help! Please mark this issue close.

Comment: @swapna: Good to know you have fixed your issue, Could you please self answer your solution and fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is resolved by adding the redirection headers which got stripped off for binaries on the load balance for the content service.  Thanks!